# How create qmltypes file in debug

Tags: qml, qt5

I have build an extension plugin in debug mode
When I try to run qmlplugindump I get

```
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.12.0/qml/qmlextensionplugins/imports/typelist.qml:3:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "TimeExample": The plugin 'C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.12.0/qml/qmlextensionplugins/imports/TimeExample/qmlqtimeexampleplugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)
```

How can I run qmlplugindump on debug extension?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have to rebuild your Qt bundle in Debug mode.

Comment: Thanks - I am new at all of this, so how do I go about rebuild Qt in debug mode?

Comment: @GrahamSim The other way around. You have to rebuild your plugin in release mode..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to work with debug libraries, create libraries in release and generate plugins.qmltypes. Then use it with debug libraries. This worked in my environment.